# Barman full Backup is not getting triggered

Tags: barman

Barman full Backup is not getting triggered. Installed Barman 2.3-2 in Ubantu 18.04 . Barman is taking incremental backup perfectly but it is not taking full backup.

Barman backup command show below output ,

```
Backup start at LSN: 
This is the first backup for server h8
WAL segments preceding the current backup have been found:
        from server h8 has been removed
Starting backup copy via rsync/SSH for 20220613T132933 (5 jobs)
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include exactly what command you are using to invoke a full backup?

Answer (score 0):

When you install barman, you get a cron job in `/etc/cron.d/barman` that runs `barman cron` every minute.

That command, however, does not take any backups.

So, it's up to you to add the `barman backup server_name --wait` command in a cron of your choice (you can actually use the same `/etc/cron.d/barman` file if you so desire).

That has been discussion that `barman cron` should take backups according to the retention policy defined, but it actually doesn't, it just deletes existing backups according to that policy, but doesn't take them. See [here](https://groups.google.com/g/pgbarman/c/b9GFSb7fqVQ/m/kHa9U78MpqkJ).